# dropdown list "curtain" is somehow measured to only appear at the top of the screen

Tags: ios, xcode

[image]I am using this code: [click here](http://www.addimage.net/blog/?tag=/uiDropDownMenu) that "simulates" a dropdown menu as it works in html code.

I have programatically added the `UITextField` to my `navigationItem` using:

```
[self.navigationItem setTitleView:myUITextField];
```

My view is a `UITableView` and my controller therefore inherits from `UITableViewController`.

I have filled the table view with a number of rows of data.  I have also set up the dropdown to act on a click in my "`myUITextField`" and the dropdownlist appears correctly when the `textField` is clicked.

My problem is that if I scroll down in my list of rows on the screen and then click again on my `textField` then I can only see the bottom of the "dropdown" - so the dropdown list "curtain" is somehow measured to only appear at the top of the screen.

How can I fix this ? I reckon I need to fix the [source code here](http://www.addimage.net/blog/?tag=/uiDropDownMenu) to get it fixed.

Comment: Any screenshot/code available?

Comment: A simple solution could be to make the view scroll to the top before calling the "show dropdownlist" - Anyone can tell me how to add such a scroll event to my UITextField before the "dropdownlist" gets called